# In W8.1, reset or change login credentials for shared network folder

Tags: windows-8.1, samba, shared-folders, network-drive, credentials-manager

I have an external drive connected to my Asus RT-N66U Router and enabled the *Network Place (Samba) Share/Cloud Disk* option, this created a shared folder called `MyNetworkDrive` on the external drive. Within this shared folder I created a series of sub-folders and I then used the routers GUI to create a series of users, each with different permissions to each of the sub-folders.

Everything works great, when I first click on one of these sub-folders I'm asked for my credentials, I entered one of the users credentials to sign in and test the permissions, trouble is I left the `Remember Credentials` options checked and now I can't sign in with a different user.

I cleared out my Credential Manage, but when I go into `MyNetworkDrive`, windows still uses the existing credentials.

I tried the `Map network drive...` with the `Connect using different credentials` option, but it says:

> The network folder specified is currently mapped using a different
>   user name and password. To connect using a different user name and
>   password, first disconnect any existing mappings to this network
>   share.

Is there any way to reset or change the login credentials of a shared network folder?

Comment: It's likely you still have a connection open to the remote system. Issue `net list` from the command prompt and then `net use /d` any of the connections to the remote system.

Comment: Great! Posted it as an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely you still have a connection open to the remote system and are re-using the credentials from that connection. Issue `net list` from the command prompt and then `net use /d` to delete any of the remaining connections to the remote system.